# Console after installing guests with KVM and virt-install

Tags: linux, virtualization, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, installation

I'm trying to install a few virtual machines with KVM onto my Debian Jessie System. 
I researched a lot but have not yet found a helping answer to my problem.

I'm connected via ssh to my host machine and try to install a new guest machine by running the following command as root:

```
virt-install --connect qemu:///system -n vpsName --memory=5000 --vcpus=4 --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/nix.img,size=125 -c /home/localuser/images/debian-8.6.0-amd64-netinst.iso --graphics vnc,listen=0.0.0.0 --noautoconsole --os-type linux --os-variant generic --accelerate --network=bridge:br0 --hvm
```

After a few seconds, I get the following message:

> Domain installation still in progress. You can reconnect to 
>   the console to complete the installation process.

My precise question is now: How do I get to the installer-console with the standard install-prompts (hostname, country, ...) of the Debian installer?

One method I tried, was VNC on the opened port but I cannot connect. It asks for a password and then freezes after password-entry.

Another thing I tried was to open the ssh connection with the `-Y` option and then installed by specifying `—-graphics none --console pty,target_type=serial`. That didn't work either; I'm stuck at a frozen command line.

I'm sure, I'm not the only one who had that issue. Unfortunately I couldn't find a similar post with a helpful answer yet.

Thank you for helping me!

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to resolve my issue by using virt-manager in a ssh connection opened with `ssh -Y user@host`. That works for me, even if it would not work for automation.

Thank you.

Comment: That gives very poor performance. It is better to run virt-manager locally and have it make the ssh connection to the remote hypervisor.

Answer (score 2):

`virsh console DOMAIN` is the way to connect. You can get the domain name or number with `virsh list --all`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But then, too, I am stuck with an empty console. The issue is the installing screen, that is not shown.

Comment: I have it working with RHEL (hosts and guests), maybe Debian has it's own quirks...